# Probabilities concerning circles within circles.

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles

This problem is inspired by multiple battle royale games. In the games, there is often a boundary which closes in around players, forcing them towards a specific point so that the last players remaining must fight.

The question I have is: There is a unit circle centered at the origin of the Cartesian Plane (representing the outer boundary of the game map). Another circle of radius $a$ is centered such that it is completely inside the unit circle. It is placed randomly and fairly. Given a point $(x,y)$, what is the probability that is is within the smaller circle? How does the probability change if more circles are nested inside each other with radii of $b,c,d...$? What happens if different shapes are used?

Finally, how could I solve similar problems in the future?

Comment: So, just to be clear, you have some *fixed* point within the unit circle and you want the probability that a “random” nested circle will enclose it, correct? At first glance this seems like it will depend on how this smaller circle is chosen.

Comment: Yes. That's right.The probability will change for each point, but the point is chosen at random from the start from the set of all points in the unit circle. The probabilities that I'm asking for are at each point. Or a formula given (x,y,a) from the at the start.

Answer (score 0):

The area of a circle is proportional to the radius squared (in fact the constant of proportionality is $\pi$, formula $A=\pi r^2$). So the ratio of areas is:

$$\frac{a^2}{1^2}=a^2$$

which is also the probability.

The answer would be the same for other *[similar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_(geometry))* figures, for example a square of side length $1$ containing a smaller square of side length $a$.

With multiple figures, it is just:

$$\frac{a_i^2}{a_j^2}=\left(\frac{a_i}{a_j}\right)^2$$

where $a_i$ and $a_j$ are the radii (or whatever characteristic length is used) of the two figures you consider.

Comment: But if the original circle has radius 1 and the smaller one, 0.75, then it would have a probability 1 if the point is in the center and probability 0 if the point is on the edge. So position of the point matters.

Comment: @Tbw I think I have misunderstood the question. I thought the point $(x,y)$ was picked at random as well (uniformly distributed over the larger disk). You want an answer that depends on both $\| (x,y)\|$ and $a$ instead.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I shouldn't have said that the point was randomly chosen.